# Use public key string to decrypt in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, public-key-encryption

I have the public key string:

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAvL+UegLeWJ1KLh6WEfbW kGcA+vj4G/k6iIz9OWCb9t3maokH+Oz/bNB8PGlwmH2aCBmqXPv9p3hexcujUsNC jFahCAz84tT7M4rR2GGwVWyY9PJ98rZbbvD9PLG380cqZs+vlwYT16bv5t+braiJ WhrAgwKF0eZyID6DzRnDCG7HbKr6sL1h7QD1WHBljplV+TinIeWoyBIWPJdqEAUs js1wXWkFPIb5x0W7kAzWc0+oH3gDD3kGv+t/p2DsbUuOYYSZgZB8Lx1AKiWVRERt 90tWH9uytulSxvwoONBriasH7VlSXyi5ve6AA4+FG/HExiPNN5Lh34kNP6l5CTc+ yaCDHewYQeqDdgP+GurgdV9ZCM4P7c6Ky7GZBs8sAAAXevch8ggf9XGjEsLl++c7 G5E4FO6kNmloL3nogRLJ8P8w/s53Y0g4ih2hdJFfqJ3l/fIolvldR17nA3oZBHTo OuOSR/JK1KWvkl/C9I1lHO70zrgvr7wtpW2YbdBHvvTu5aTK8oIMNoZ8lhWdKFYG aiQWvfsM/IPXbFKQbDQachn5ZHYLc4wXi1uBHYnPCjZM3Fq6wc1oSnRZ77CI8crf To7TJFfXO20VtSdwUq0SCrQ1wxttK8uH22c/YUXPld+K6fW13tspWz653gnw5FPd 8bFQQByVkrcihbyuXWjUSMkCAwEAAQ== -----END PUBLIC KEY-----

and want to use it to encrypt a message, however when I run the code below it gives me the following error:

Warning: openssl_public_encrypt(): key parameter is not a valid public key i ...

```
<?php 

$unformatted_pub= "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIICIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAg8AMIICCgKCAgEAvL+UegLeWJ1KLh6WEfbW kGcA+vj4G/k6iIz9OWCb9t3maokH+Oz/bNB8PGlwmH2aCBmqXPv9p3hexcujUsNC jFahCAz84tT7M4rR2GGwVWyY9PJ98rZbbvD9PLG380cqZs+vlwYT16bv5t+braiJ WhrAgwKF0eZyID6DzRnDCG7HbKr6sL1h7QD1WHBljplV+TinIeWoyBIWPJdqEAUs js1wXWkFPIb5x0W7kAzWc0+oH3gDD3kGv+t/p2DsbUuOYYSZgZB8Lx1AKiWVRERt 90tWH9uytulSxvwoONBriasH7VlSXyi5ve6AA4+FG/HExiPNN5Lh34kNP6l5CTc+ yaCDHewYQeqDdgP+GurgdV9ZCM4P7c6Ky7GZBs8sAAAXevch8ggf9XGjEsLl++c7 G5E4FO6kNmloL3nogRLJ8P8w/s53Y0g4ih2hdJFfqJ3l/fIolvldR17nA3oZBHTo OuOSR/JK1KWvkl/C9I1lHO70zrgvr7wtpW2YbdBHvvTu5aTK8oIMNoZ8lhWdKFYG aiQWvfsM/IPXbFKQbDQachn5ZHYLc4wXi1uBHYnPCjZM3Fq6wc1oSnRZ77CI8crf To7TJFfXO20VtSdwUq0SCrQ1wxttK8uH22c/YUXPld+K6fW13tspWz653gnw5FPd 8bFQQByVkrcihbyuXWjUSMkCAwEAAQ== -----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

$unformatted_priv = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- MIIJQwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCCS0wggkpAgEAAoICAQDFrm2aDzAp2SEx b89HeyPrkq0mBfA7o4BNhUAC9pO0JcGZdDHJyE1cN8ZwK4H0sYKYUllZDvVlx6rQ MpoD9UJsbvlhc+xJtNFFqqxdVCqy/1hh9QXZ6xXAbGDKNuEoueD7/9IlDbJGE+y6 4RVxuhe38Ed5S6ZHCdgmuJ5OPs4GE45huskXNxh2mhBQ4BgNV5wKSsULz+ApdE+j 3s+1L3gOuZB/Rby3Qn3mbhYovpF+fFGUqL6jtNaytv5zAi8595FSaayP/l9perBm ODniNok/ZqzVPuF/K04GZtIhPZjW7SDjypJDXJYH7kjeMCrmyemi/FeP+kKSNDqm Hmwm7tFbgSVhjqMq6m5nIGMFUByNhsejt++ygVAc9hOEN0q2AShsDd5pXRieU40P TyFDfv4Cd7uXX1lDtyTgMk5XryyLddjBcxjaJznILTmtsp7ynEXC6KkPA1n85elp RlZUmt7tFQ7KjLWI/b+M69FfBx6Hh+WsEUE+VsjOcp0iJJBkzCuIO60cF2H379US O5dVYd4ZcVW+8Y/GjFswl9TexuPXEWiDsRR7QTI2ZQW8ueCKxHGU8MjN+q+9stTE azTAQwAFnntGP/jflIiTXnnmW+bLuvB0FGuacRHu0pdZ8Q4K6pW349L9WT49UkmA 2AQ6qSCZog0uBsepd/K5tVxrDlyJFwIDAQABAoICADimVPhqU9YaSD3fmdoVOuT+ gqo7121v3IvanM58lTVyAHoWZ1I5GZpMzYxFm5dg61j1eG9iLwb84kGJzsNFnMRw RP0deGBi9fnuADk6roXfURe5XPTnPrOHG3G3qmy+X/A3jqRZuXYFrbicWkXeG3/1 1rW27S68bnoiPBOWQfpRzmLJYWlKu7L5UaWropjoO2pjpPZOmyGmGFCQwJtewBwQ J42hkYQ/BM9tSuJgQleqDsL4XLGTWFecw2x3+sq03KtuZypYrkUPCNAyWrwt/sTx iqQNwhdsdI63Fo66FTu6dstwuNufA8vACJfL2++Je2/eusUi5cL6PrhuTXYWyF3c T8yA5+A1oS+sXQRQzMWP5Jsu7PDKWTSnB294zVVLw3v1x4T/qkJ1Kd5VNZVQqlFf hi7FqxC+CMvyULfK4g+6p5CY87QwgkuxrYN27+jQNFNTpkcb2LrrPRz/ogw7KHm1 rpvnHnhHWmrYOecxDBXqFO34zsLbVHuLH+lFvIsupgtIKT/FtZ2XYOQPvnTqiK6a AKNAnV8wFKK6pdD1O3JmNMpBbCvfm4fKhJ+Wumu0tyY/qE8ay95gJkf8mDal3CVa xMMqXVEbxXZGDrhYXHpjZqPr0eKkh9f1QoiPxaRXfEIAhvggpdd5SYzUPvI5zZIS eqGx125kP/eDQR+n1TtJAoIBAQD0q2rbNBmdLBH9D1eva0NsJlswrVOm+YRIAshN +89wvAN/2YKS78tPXl9snjnviAOAHNVL4yNpemWmxipVg5C6SOYMETN8Xo/UGzE0 yfLReO2ndukyX63CaUaiZMDz++ARuyW7GpWPj6xrmt1j2chpvFFilbORreXNlzSe AwVL7jLwSGp84CF2Pgb+Mm9yap+DRr8k6C99LN/6xYJbajzqIu6e6PtFSxx01fce 6JD0AdSfc9q3KZ65B8uw3WGQXRGXcoUPnsc/HA9leZJlhBTGzDShSIogqbC89vKK YE8ux3PK+T12m6DFkvITsaqIHE2o70843DEFNZcJLE4k9r/lAoIBAQDO1fXfmylh aeYNmoWYt6LwxH2ZdGZAHpZjA1QAJHd1TRoskOgOCY22KztQLDqyLv4cVX0QuU6J pdE1R+SRNSL2BTp4YLZ2bPixUjaWL2br1tupVy+WgPwPNC5oQPbhnMWxy+15gR14 X5UBNF/SCDL2s9enLUHfBrkpB/6KqFl5N3WRxolaNJaE85dNHfRbW6JZesm/+DER SE+5QTNZfY9jyjseUqFCgTgktswPwdeO41PHPofkfYgANjoMYeA+b9I5aXrMNqmD nGLiNe6yuYhaBI1GfDBvq2wLzkKl9rKLcvlSSokUwY1BD9Z7NcE0CNZoJMBjOtbm fJVN+hFr6f1LAoIBAQCC8hc/eDPZNZPvDz4LqWmtQR3/AFTMAbC1ZZ/UdNeB624o B75la6cxND34APra4r2U3FmfwtHaCuLKjjZsC/zyZj+Q58fZYTay+1arfQXS7Fit DuwhxKlXakaedTP7oKs8ch/wcnrnGara8Ehav10OkfYwwBQZ/KsIDEvh4ZX9HF/w z6EGcmIWSX4un8mbv8rdVIjKdOWtpc2+BeUNjd9KJCX3sJOCc3+oXDdlOG0T2sL0 D+pXqxPCzZRLdUBZJiZbGrRyNrVGZnsrARTD9hu0hegJBay/bHIlwDjwrDjUvXSQ hjJJ/2LdOxcKSUUOka9SobmRoe8ubY8HHso36EOtAoIBAQCr+KXX5xB+2CfZA7M0 iOrHOPgdEPS7NzNe27OJ8sgIFbU/fLQUh8j1v/gu7rdW00+gi0vTDd/I/r91h3L5 cK7C0xIMaI0M5gnYlTyhnoP6bshwgfclMdVhZsd3Exyx9UFCVQX70miIXyBqwfsx jHOjP2B8tVphbxugi+8Npm/OI1hzfhlRkQvdOxN/oPo8w3G26Cq6nEdf0TnIE/f3 3jfMhqakzZsayom9rOb56veo7EYKEWm3hs//LRcSmIZ0I1EtPxBEnuZOcUaeQq1W mIBQKBy2kCdNkb/iCPrNNtK4sz2tOB/FzC//+oUgKE+dTgPGz1fOqWtodAlHrjWx /fkFAoIBADk3d8FxNXgpv8imDzUTg3ONN9sbzqHjb9/6HKAYpN4Ez535Kr9rIJ1U D+z4VC7X5Gd5GrikoqsikotNEMJmYR/5Z0ojbZPdcaLWsIWXiAQksQOCodloQ+6+ QkJ2U8Be9y41F2psiq4s0E326rufobj3NSyk+5LYizrjdB/S7CeuehQnq7nA99A6 7uvmD4Kmh+EfDggS7sKQoIS9nLzraGpdjokFk56vtKH0TbUlrgoMTdUuNUBRSD8R O0KT1VLB4wrlMAuVQ+wKs/dOFRwHIMNl2EaBoXCkYE4sjl9776r1kIUJ/ZDt7+FZ H6CKoxjdh97Zzxo1Up2PTOOpcXfE6GA= -----END PRIVATE KEY-----";

$data = 'plaintext data goes here';

// Encrypt the data to $encrypted using the public key
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $unformatted_pub);

// Decrypt the data using the private key and store the results in $decrypted
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $unformatted_priv);

echo $decrypted;

//echo $pubKey;


?>
```

I am unsure how to properly encode the public key, any and all help is much appreciated.

Comment: Bad news, you can't decrypt with a public key.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone: "I have the public key string ... and want to use it to decrypt a message"

Comment: @JamesKPolk What do you mean you can't decrypt with the public key? When something is encrypted with a private key, it can be decrypted with the public key.

Comment: Ah my bad, I meant encrypt. I am sorry what do you mean with dont remove the new lines for the public key?

Comment: @nonein see the following answer for an asymmetric encryption example:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432514/php-encryption-with-multiple-keys/47434412#47434412 - you use public key to encrypt and the private key to decrypt.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone You can do it either way, either can encrypt, the other key is required to decrypt. The use case is what matters.  Encrypted with a private key and sending the cipher text to someone to decrypt with your public key is used to prove your identity.  Encrypting with someone's public key is done to ensure only they can decrypt it.

Comment: Yeah but your not meant to, thats like saying give the end party the private key and you keep the public one.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone in that example there is no public key string i.e. no "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- MIICIjANBgkq..." so I am unsure what you exactly you mean.

Comment: @nonein its in the variables :/

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Encrypting with your private key is a VERY common use case, primarily in signing. There is not enough in the OPs example to tell us if their intent is to do that.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yeah I get that, but if I have to copy paste the key, then what do I do, i.e. I have the key above how do I format that so I can use it.

Comment: @nonein your code shows you generating a public key/private key pair, and then trying to encrypt with an unrelated public key, decrypting with the private key you just generated. That is never going to work.

Comment: Yeah sorry will update now, I realise my mistake. Still give the same error

Comment: @nonein the line breaks are important, you need to leave those in.

Comment: Ah okay, when I echo out a generated public and private key, they leave them out, thats probably why this is wrong. Is there a way to echo them and leave the line breaks in?

Comment: So, uh... you're going to want to throw away that keypair and generate a new one, seeing as you've posted both public and private on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code generates the keys and everything works as expected, but your hard coding a public key which won't work for the private key which gets been generated:

```
<?php     
$config = array(
    "digest_alg" => "sha512",
    "private_key_bits" => 4096,
    "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);

// Extract the private key from $res to $privKey
openssl_pkey_export($res, $privKey);

// Extract the public key from $res to $pubKey
$pubKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($res);
$pubKey = $pubKey["key"];

$data = 'plaintext data goes here';

// Encrypt the data to $encrypted using the public key
openssl_public_encrypt($data, $encrypted, $pubKey);

// Decrypt the data using the private key and store the results in $decrypted
openssl_private_decrypt($encrypted, $decrypted, $privKey);

echo $decrypted;
?>
```

Instead you should be doing the following to *test*, generate your keys then hardcode both:

```
<?php  
$pubKey = '
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----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-----END PUBLIC KEY-----';

$privKey = '-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----';

$encrypted = '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';

// Decrypt the data using the private key and store the results in $decrypted
openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted), $decrypted, $privKey);

echo $decrypted;
?>
```

Which will output `plaintext data goes here`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I just changed my code, but it still gives me an error, how are you formatting the priv and pub keys? Mine are just one long string as thats how the echo relayed it back to me

Comment: You need to view the page source and then copy the keys, or wrap in a `<pre></pre>` tag, else new lines get lost.

Comment: You are the god damn man! Thanks a bunch I really appreciate it.